# Hyper-V vm can ping host but host cannot ping Hyper-V vm?

Tags: windows, networking, hyper-v, ipv6

When ping host from hyper-v VM, it works both with ipv4 or ipv6.

```
Pinging MyHost [fe80::3549:ee49:a75c:619c%9] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from fe80::3549:ee49:a75c:619c%9: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::3549:ee49:a75c:619c%9: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::3549:ee49:a75c:619c%9: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::3549:ee49:a75c:619c%9: time<1ms

Ping statistics for fe80::3549:ee49:a75c:619c%9:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

When ping Hyper-V VM from host, ipv4 time out.

```
Pinging win-hyperv [192.168.1.126] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.126:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

And ipv6 got

```
Ping request could not find host win-hyperv. Please check the name and try again.
```

Why host use IPv4 while another way use IPv6?

Comment: There's a lot of reasons why IPv6 pings might work and IPv4 Pings wouldn't.  The primary being that IPv6 can actually autosense config details to put itself in the correct subnets.  IPv4 requires the DHCP server or static config to do it for it.  I suggest you disable IPv6 on the VM, retry the ping (Because now it will only use IPv4) and see if the VM can see the host on IPv4.

Comment: It's also possible to just specify the type of IP you want to use in the command [syntax here](http://www.computerhope.com/pinghlp.htm).  You can just use the `-4` or `-6` switches to test connectivity with.

Comment: I tried -4 and -6 and -6 got the error of "could not find". The question has been updated.

Comment: Well, things make a lot more sense now.  Is your VM statically configured for IP or getting DHCP?  Also, can you try the force IPv4 ping on the VM to the host?  I have a sneaking suspicion it won't resolve to anything, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Yes, force IPv4 ping on the VM to host works too.

Comment: Then, likely your problem is on the host.  You might have to add in the hosts network adapter configurations and the virtual switch configuration.  Off the top of my head, I'd say your host has at least two adapters with IP's in the same subnet and is mistakenly trying to ping out the one not attached to the right virtual switch.  But, that's just a wild guess without knowing your exact config.

Comment: HI, have you checked the host based Firewall on the VM? is it allowing ICMP traffic? this would explain why the VM can ping the host but not the other way round.

Answer (score 2):

have you checked the host based Firewall on the VM? is it allowing ICMP traffic? this would explain why the VM can ping the host but not the other way round

Comment: This was the issue for me - found the rule "File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request - ICMPv4-In)" inside the VM firewall and enabled it. Not sure why it was disabled.

Answer (score 0):

If you checked the firewalls, subnets, adapters, and have one-way-pings, check your local group policy.

Start>gpedit.msc>Computer Management>Windows Settings>Security Settings>Local Policies>User Rights Assignment>Deny Access to this computer from the Network
Double-Click, Remove your account from this policy.